# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/service/class$

Tags: hibernate, maven, tomcat

I am working in the production deployment of a project based on JSF and Hibernate. The project is built with Maven. The application works perfectly when running it on a tomcat localhost servlet in Windows, but when I try to deploy it on Ubuntu 16.04 machine (also using tomcat) I get some hibernate related errors.
I know I have posted a lot of code but I do not exactly know where the error is located.

This is the tomcat error log from catalina.out in the Ubuntu server. This log is located in /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out:

```
02-Oct-2017 11:25:55.859 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-13] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
02-Oct-2017 11:25:55.861 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-13] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;$
02-Oct-2017 11:25:56.120 ADVERTENCIA [http-nio-8080-exec-13] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{beanLogin.validateUsernamePassword}: j$
 javax.faces.FacesException: #{beanLogin.validateUsernamePassword}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at resources.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:39)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at eLagun.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:37)
        at eLagun.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
        at eLagun.Dao.<clinit>(Dao.java:29)
        at beans.beanLogin.validateUsernamePassword(beanLogin.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/service/class$
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
        at eLagun.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:29)
        ... 43 more

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

The following script fragments are the ones that I think the problem could be in.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elagun_1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">USER</property>
        <property name="connection.password">PASS</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <mapping class="eLagun.Familiar" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Paciente" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Test" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Pregunta" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Resultado" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Medico" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Respuesta" />
        <mapping class="eLagun.Respuesta_pregunta" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil class to create a SessionFactory instance:

```
package eLagun;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static ServiceRegistryBuilder registry;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Paciente.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Pregunta.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Familiar.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Test.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Resultado.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Medico.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Respuesta.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Respuesta_pregunta.class);

            registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
            registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        System.out.println("entro en hibernate util get session factory");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void closeSessionFactory() {
        if ((sessionFactory != null) && (sessionFactory.isClosed() == false)) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is the Dao method autenticarMedico() where the app is crashing as the log error shows. I remark that this works on windows localhost. It crashes when attemting to log in as a Medico so when using Dao.autenticarMedico(user, pwd):

```
public static int autenticarMedico(String username, String password) {

        Query q = session.createQuery(
                "" + "from Medico " + "where userMedico =\'" + username + "\' AND password = \'" + password + "\'");

        if(q.list().size() <= 0)
            return -1;
        else {
            Medico medico = (Medico) q.list().get(0);
            return medico.getIdMedico();
        }
    }
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eLagun2</groupId>
    <artifactId>eLagun2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.SP1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the project structure in order to show other libraries and dependencies being used:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqfW2.png)

PS: I have already tried to move the hibernate.cfg.xml to the resources package as some people suggested in other posts but it did not work.

Comment: You get aNoSuchMethodError `NoSuchMethodError`. Looks like incompatible jars.

Comment: Yes, I have come up with that conclusion but I think i have already cleaned up the incompatible jars, do you see any other jars which could be conflicting? You have all the jars in the Project Structure image.

Comment: it must be one of the hibernate jars

Comment: Solved, ty so much I had been struggling with this for one week. I had deleted the jars from the build path but for some reason the war was exporting all the jars in the same folder so the ones deleted from the build path were still being imported.